# Android Studio doesn't find support classes

Tags: android

I'm pretty mad about this.
I keep getting

[image]

And I've done pretty much everything I could google:

- Rebuild Project
- Synced with the Gradle
- Changed the API preview
- Changed the Theme

Nothing seems to work, yet on my Laptop the project does actually render.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you add external libraries required?? Supportv4

Comment: Yes i added external libraries. As i said, it's something with the PC, because on my Laptop it works.

Comment: Change api level for rendering screen

Comment: ... reading would be really nice :D